# "Questa è riuscita a pararla"?

Tags: verbs, grammar, agreement, word-order, past-participle

Io credo che in presenza di un soggetto maschile si dovrebbe dire:
"Questa è **riuscito** a pararla" oppure " Questa la è **riuscito** a parare"

Sarebbe corretta se il soggetto fosse femminile.

Le mie impressioni sono corrette oppure invece no?
Lo dico perché mi pare di averlo sentito da un telecronista, quindi non so se abbia sbagliato lui oppure mi sbaglio io.

Comment: Esatto: se il soggetto è maschile l'espressione corretta dovrebbe essere "questa è riuscito a pararla". Il secondo esempio che citi ("Questa la è riuscito a pararla") però è sbagliato: quel "la" è fuori posto, "questa" è già sufficiente per indicare la palla.

Comment: @ZabZonk (1) Le risposte vanno scritte più giù :). (2) Non direi che *Questa la è riuscito a parare* sia scorretto, certo è molto colloquiale e dà molta più enfasi all'oggetto, ma non scorretto specialmente nel parlato.

Comment: @ZabZonk: In prima approssimazione sono d'accordo con te (ma occhio che l'OP non dice “Questa la è riuscito a pararla”, che effettivamente sarebbe pleonastica). Ripensandoci, però, sospetto che la cosa sia più sottile. “Ha parato la cosa X” > “È riuscito a parare la cosa X”, e siamo d'accordo. Ma quando l'oggetto è costituito da un pronome atono che viene prima del verbo, avrei qualche dubbio: “L'ha parata” > “La è riuscita a parare”, forse? In un certo senso “riuscire” si comporta come un verbo servile (“L'ha dovuta parare”, “L'ha potuta parare”).

Comment: @Denis Nardin Grazie! Non voleva essere una risposta ma un commento: una risposta richiede più argomentazioni. Il

Comment: @DaG Hai ragione, ho visto un'enclitica che non c'era. Tuttavia l'esempio continua a stonarmi anche così: "Questa la è riuscito a parare" suona quasi dialetto veneto o trentino. Ma in effetti è l'unico caso, anche tra quelli che citi, ad avere qualcosa che non va: con i verbi servili - ed anche con "riuscire" al presente - non ci troverei niente di sbagliato ("questa la vuole/deve/può parare", "questa la riesce a parare" sono del tutto accettabili). (1/2)

Comment: @DaG Probabilmente è la combinazione col passato prossimo di "riuscire" a far saltare tutto, perché "riuscire" si accompagna nel genere col soggetto: col passato prossimo dei servili invece funziona perché il servile si adatta al genere del pronome ("questa l'ha voluta parare"). (2/2)

Comment: Beh, @DaG: si tratta di una dislocazione a sinistra.

Answer (score 1):

> Questa la è riuscito a parare

non è corretta in italiano e suona molto male (potrebbe essere usata in qualche espressione regionale, ad esempio provo ad ipotizzare in toscano, con elisione della lettera a: "Questa l'è riuscito a parare", ma sempre riferita ad un soggetto maschile).

Il participio passato concorda sempre in genere e numero con il soggetto quando ha per ausiliare il verbo essere (vedi [qui](https://library.weschool.com/domanda/participio-passato-e-concordanze-11019.html#:%7E:text=Il%20participio%20passato%20concorda%20sempre,Mario%20e%20Marco%20sono%20ingrassati.))

Gianluigi è *riuscito* a pararla questa (punizione/palla).

Loredana è *riuscita* a pararla questa (punizione/palla).

Comment: La fonte che citi non mi sembra molto autorevole. Chi è Antonio Marini?

Comment: @DaG, non conosco l'autore, ma è il primo articolo che ho trovato che corrispondeva a quello che volevo dire.

Comment: Capisco, ma se citiamo il primo articolo che troviamo che ne sappiamo se quello che dice è giusto? Magari uno fa una domanda sulla forma della Terra e io trovo un articolo di terrapiattisti. :) (Non sto dando nessuna valutazione su quel sito in particolare, che appunto ignoro.)